# How to solve RFC_CONVERSION_FIELD error in SAP?

Tags: abap, saprfc, pyrfc

My Python script queries the rows of table `AUFK` via RFC which have `BUKRS=1110`, but I get the error:

> RFC_CONVERSION_FIELD
>
> Convertion error "rfc_ucs_to_str" from charset 4110 to charset 4103
> (translated from german to english by me)

The shortdump seems to show a wrong line number (line 1), but I guess this is not true.

My code works fine since several weeks. That's why I guess there must be something wrong with the data (a database row in AUFK).

Is there a way to debug which line of AUFK is broken? Or is the error in my code, and not the data?

I read [the SAP note 2504815](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2504815), but it does not help. The client is Python (pyRFC) and the server is a 7.40 Unicode system.

Comment: 4110 = UTF-8, 4103 = UTF-16LE. It's theorically impossible that one character cannot be converted. But maybe your RFC client program is not UTF-16LE, maybe a ASCII-like format? You could create a test program which sends a non-ASCII character like CJK U+4142 for instance and make sure you receive it correctly (if your RFC client is ASCII-like, it would interpret it incorrectly "AB").

Comment: @SandraRossi I guess there is a broken character in the utf8. Maybe a string in latin1. SAP thinks it is utf8, but it isn't. I guess every conversion would fail.

Comment: You said that your JSON is truncated at 33 mb? Are you able to locate the end of this string to see what kind of name, etc, it is? Maybe it will be then easier to find it in the table AUFK?

Comment: @Jagger in my case the cut happens in row which does not contain any special characters. All chars are pure 7-bit ascii. No umlauts. It happens, if I select all rows of column AUFK. The cut happens at the row where AUFNR=000008189486. If I only pull this row, everything is fine. But I guess above question is a different one. But maybe the cut happens because there were  broken rows before this one. Rows where latin1 chars are, where sap thinks it is utf8.

Comment: What FM do you use to read table?

Comment: @Suncatcher it is a custom RFC FM.

Comment: so it worth giving code of this FM because the cause of the issue may be in the buggy code

Comment: @Suncatcher I am sorry. I can't reproduce this any more.